# The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine. Error

Tags: c#, ms-access-2010, oledbexception

Currently, I am trying to run my c# code on my Windows x64 platform. But I cannot add my data into the MS Access. Its saying 
`Additional information: The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.`. I tried to check my office application versions and got to know they are 32 bits application.

I tried to search for some solution but it didnt worked for me. This are the methods I have tried:

1. Installing Microsoft Access Engine 2010
2. Changing it to Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0 (still the same error pops up)

This is my connection string code:

```
Connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\FacesDatabase.accdb;
                                        Persist Security Info=False";
```

Can I know how to solve this error. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using 64-bit but still having problem even after installing AccessDatabaseEngine, see [this post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1d5c04c7-157f-4955-a14b-41d912d50a64/how-to-fix-error-the-microsoftaceoledb120-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine?forum=vstsdb), it solved the problem for me.

ie. You need to install this [Access Database Engine](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=23734)

Kindly check and confirm.

Comment: Its still the same. Actually how many database engine i should install? I already have access 2010 engine and now 2007 engine.

Comment: try this [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20411366/the-microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine) I think this problem is already solve in the past

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this same error after previously being able to complete similar operations.  I didn't try downloading any of the mentioned packages since I didn't have them previously installed and things were working fine without them.  IT at my job did a 'Repair' on the Microsoft Office 2013 installation (Control Panel > Programs > Add/Remove - Select Change then 'Repair').  Took a few minutes to complete but fixed everything and no longer get this error.