# Unable to Scaffold-DbContext with EntityFrameworkCore.Jet

Tags: entity-framework-core, jet-ef-provider

**I've been trying to generate the Entity Framework Models for an existing Database.**

I'm using the [`EntityFrameworkCore.Jet`](https://github.com/bubibubi/JetEntityFrameworkProvider)-Provider (v2.1.0 preview 5) with `EntityFrameworkCore` (v2.1.2) in Visual Studio 2017. I used the following command within the Package Manager Console:

```
PM> Scaffold-DbContext -Connection "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\..\workplace\TestProject\demo.accdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=****;" -Provider EntityFrameworkCore.Jet -OutputDir Models -verbose
```

which gave me this output:

```
Using project 'TestProject'.
Using startup project 'TestProject'.
Build started...
Build succeeded.
...
Using assembly 'TestProject'.
Using startup assembly 'TestProject'.
Using application base 'C:\..\workplace\TestProject\bin\Debug'.
Using working directory 'C:\..\workplace\TestProject'.
Using root namespace 'TestProject'.
Using project directory 'C:\..\workplace\TestProject\'.
Using configuration file 'C:\..\workplace\TestProject\bin\Debug\TestProject.exe.config'.
Finding design-time services for provider 'EntityFrameworkCore.Jet'...
Using design-time services from provider 'EntityFrameworkCore.Jet'.
Finding design-time services referenced by assembly 'TestProject'.
No referenced design-time services were found.
Finding IDesignTimeServices implementations in assembly 'TestProject'...
No design-time services were found.
System.InvalidOperationException: Der 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'-Provider ist nicht auf dem lokalen Computer registriert.
...
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
```

> Der 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'-Provider ist nicht auf dem lokalen Computer registriert.

Which translates to

> The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.

At first I expected this to be the case and did some research which brought me [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1d5c04c7-157f-4955-a14b-41d912d50a64/how-to-fix-error-quotthe-microsoftaceoledb120-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local?forum=vstsdb) and I followed the given solution, but the Problem persisted. Looking into the folder `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared` contains the subfolders `OFFICE12`, `OFFICE14` and `OFFICE16` which each hold an `ACEOLEDB.DLL`.

Confirmed through use in a Code First approach **the provider is actually registered and usable!** But when used in the Package Manager it can't be found. Am I missing some specific reference?

Since the exact same ConnectionString is working when used with CodeFirst what could be the Issue? Or is EntityFrameworkCore.Jet not enabled for Database-First Approach?

Comment: Is this useful?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6649363/microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine

Comment: @viveknuna Sadly it is not, it's already linked in the post I have linked in my Question. Since as I said in my question I am able to connect via `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` in a Code First Test (same Database), the provider is not available in this specific context and not overall

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Revisiting this Issue, I realised that the Compile Configuration had been set to `Any CPU`.

Mind that I have installed `office 32bit` and the corresponding 32bit driver set (see [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1d5c04c7-157f-4955-a14b-41d912d50a64/how-to-fix-error-quotthe-microsoftaceoledb120-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local?forum=vstsdb) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20411693/8471295))

While Code First will run in the `Any CPU` Configuration, the Package-Manager-Console does have a problem with this. PMC seems to be trying to resolve the `x64`-provider in this configuration.

Switching this setting to `x86` in Visual Studio 2017 resolved that issue:

```
Using assembly 'TestProject'.
Using startup assembly 'TestProject'.
Using application base 'C:\..\workplace\TestProject\bin\x86\Debug'.
Using working directory 'C:\..\workplace\TestProject'.
Using root namespace 'TestProject'.
Using project directory 'C:\..\workplace\TestProject\'.
Using configuration file 'C:\..\workplace\TestProject\bin\x86\Debug\TestProject.exe.config'.
```

After switching the Compile Configuration of the Project/StartupProject to `x86` PMC is able to resolve the `Microsoft.ACE.OleDb.12.0` provider and successfully scaffold the database.