# System.InvalidOperationException: The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine

Tags: .net, azure, azure-devops

I am trying to run tests using vstest in Azure DevOps. But getting the below error. Any clue what could have caused the below error?

System.InvalidOperationException: The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine..

Comment: Just checking in to see whether this issue is still blocking you now? Any update for this issue?

Comment: Does the below answer help?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a host machine issue(IIS). Please contact support and ask them to fix this.

References:

1. [The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine (server)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20411366/the-microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine)
2. https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/280/solved-the-microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-mach

Comment: Does this help you @Ramdas?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using hosted agent, you could check this doc about the [Microsoft-hosted agent configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#software).

Access Engine is not pre-installed in the microsoft-hosted agent, so the microsoft-hosted agent couldn't meet the test requirements. It may cause the error. We could use the power shell task and run the script `(New-Object system.data.oledb.oledbenumerator).GetElements() | select SOURCES_NAME, SOURCES_DESCRIPTION` to check it.

Microsoft Hosted agent `windows-2019`

[image]

Local machine

[image]

The effective way is to install [Microsoft Access Database Engine](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255) on your local machine or VM, and then you can create a self-hosted agent to run your test that require MS Access Engine.

In this situation, the correct method is that you could create a [self-hosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops) and run the test on it.