# 32 bit office running on 64 windows platform c# connection string

Tags: c#, ms-office, connection-string, 32bit-64bit

I have an application that connect with access and import,export data to sqlserver.
Access is 32 bits and my application and pc runs on 64 bits.
When trying to connect c# to access with this connection string   `("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + AccessDatabaseName + "; User Id=admin;Password=;";)`

if gives me this error

`"The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine."`

When trying giving it `Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0` provider same errors occurs.
Is there any solution by changing the connection string ? without installing the access database engine ?

Thanks

Comment: No you need to change your Target Platform to x86, [see this question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17716207/the-microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine-w/17716238#17716238)

Comment: I have tried it,same results.
giammin how can i install it ?