# Some issue about "The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine."

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, excel, oledb

I get the issue

> Some issue about "The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not
>   registered on the local machine..

I've already installed Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable and 2007 one on the server machine which has iis and SQL server.
When I am debugging in VS on the server, there is no error and it works well; although when I am trying to import excel other PC's via internet with HTTP protocol it returns error, if I try it on the server via http web page it returns `"The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine."` this error.

I can only use it just debugging and already have access database engine, how can I fix it?

Here is my connectionstrings in web config

```
<add name ="Excel03ConString" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR={1}'"/>
<add name ="Excel07ConString" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR={1}'"/>
```

ps:I've got the error both oledb.4.0 and oledb.12.0

Comment: Are you on x86 or x64?  The OLEDB provider does not work for 64 bit. You may try recompiling your code for x86 and see if that helps.

Comment: @JakobChristensen the server is 64bit. How can I know the project is running on x64 or not and how can I change it to x86 and if I change, will it healty, will it happen any problem?

//edit: It works fine while debugging in VS, may I change it in IIS or in VS?

Comment: In VS check your platform target for your project.  See this image: http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-ocoFqAWeR-A/TajKY72tGUI/AAAAAAAAACg/UAqRzM06JOU/s1600/project_settings.png.  You can set the platform target to x86.

Comment: I couldn't find anyithing like that, there is no choice.
Prjoect was opened as a web site, may be this is the cause that I couldn't find.

Comment: There's a 64-bit version of ACE - strings attached, though. http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On IIS7 and higher I believe you can enable 32-bit on the application pool.

Open [inetmgr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763170.ASPX) and go to application pools.  For the application pool that your web site is using, click "Advanced settings" in the pane to the right.

Find the setting "Enable 32 Bit Applications" and change the value to "True".

Instead of changing the default ASP.NET application pool, you should create your own application pool for your web site.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your working platform from Configuration Manager.

Link:[How to change working platform (x86/x64) (You can check the answer of Steve)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17716207/the-microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine-w)

Comment: Please provide some context for the link.