# Read from Excel sheet c#

Tags: c#, excel, driver, ole

I am trying to read an excel sheet using this code

```
Dictionary<string, DataTable> tables = new Dictionary<string, DataTable>();//Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 
string sConnection = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=yes'", filePath);
OleDbConnection oleExcelConnection = new OleDbConnection(sConnection);

foreach(string sheet in Sheets)
{
    DataTable dt = GetDataTable("SELECT * from [" + sheet + "$]", sConnection);

    tables.Add(sheet, dt); 
}
```

After I run it got this exception `The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.`

and I downloaded the component from here 'https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=23734'
and worked correctly but when I deploy it it doesn't work 
anyone can help ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17716207/the-microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine-w/17716238#17716238

Comment: Thanks, but this exception arises only from the deployed code, I don't know what's the problem with that .

Comment: Did you have the driver installed on the client machine?

Comment: I am just testing that on the server locally after I deployed, and I have installed the driver on the server from the link that I posted above ..

Comment: why don't you do a google search on the following error and you will find tons of solutions / suggestions on how to fix your issue. `C# 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.`

Comment: You can see in the question I faced this exception and found a solution for it that was the need to install the driver , and then worked correctly after the deploy we have a problem @MethodMan

Comment: I have done much search with no benefit , that is way I am asking here @MethodMan

Comment: you must be searching incorrectly in all due respect.. here try looking here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6649363/microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine

Comment: OK I read that answer before and I installed the driver as I said million times above :) ,  please don't judge,if you just couldn't read the question carefully please sir

Comment: @Hana Did you download that file on your production server..?

Comment: @MethodMan That question is in relation to operations within excel, not programatically. While they may stem from the same issue, they are not duplicates.

Comment: @Hana The issue can be resolved via Steve's recommended duplicate target. It doesn't work on deployment because clearly the architecture of the two servers (your local and production) are different. Please read it clearly

Comment: @Rob I am testing on the production sever, am not accessing it remotely through my local machine's browser , and I have downloaded that file on the production server also. I changed the debugging version and that didn't work also , I even tried to enable the application bool 32 bit

Comment: @Hana Did you check the version of the driver? Is your production server 64 bit? What version is the driver?

Answer (score 0):

Please use execlDatareader for nugget package and use this code .Please change path to user file location.

execldatareader  work everywhere but ole db must be installed on machine if u goes live with ole db can give u error.

```
string path1 = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/" + sessionManagement.GetUserId()), Path.GetFileName(model.FileName));
                FileStream stream = System.IO.File.Open(path1, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

                IExcelDataReader reader = null;
                DataSet result = new DataSet();
                try
                {
                    if (path1.EndsWith(".xls"))
                    {
                        reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(stream);
                        reader.IsFirstRowAsColumnNames = true;
                    }
                    if (path1.EndsWith(".xlsx"))
                    {
                        reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream);
                        reader.IsFirstRowAsColumnNames = true;
                    }
                    result = reader.AsDataSet();
                    reader.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Dispose();
   }
                DataTable dt = result.Tables[0];
```

Comment: thanks @Harvinder , i will try this method but please do you know if I can read all the sheets in the excel file or get one by name ?

Comment: I tried this code and I could just read the first sheet in the excel , do you know how can I read all the sheets there ?

Comment: Can you use for each when add into datatable   ...in my code I specify the DataTable dt = result.Tables[0]

Comment: addend every table into datatable

Comment: when I try to access the second sheet DataTable dt = result.Tables[1] it gives me exception , that it wasn't found , I can see there's only one sheey loaded in the dataset ,, I don't know why it doesn't load all the sheets

Answer (score 0):

Your MS ACE driver version (x86 / x64) must match targeted platform of your VS solution. Click on Project menu>Properties. Select "Build" tab. On your screen, locate a.combobox placed immediate right of label [Platform target:].change value of combobox from "Any CPU" to x86 or x64 whichever version you have and you will get rid of that error.