# VS Express 2012 Installer Options

Tags: visual-studio-2012, crystal-reports, wix, nsis, infragistics

I've built a project using VS Express 2012, and obviously there are no installer project templates available for me to use to create a setup/installer routine.

I've looked up some alternatives and have found `NSIS` and `WiX`, but I'm not too sure about the details of these.

My project uses an MS Access back-end, along with Crystal Reports files, `.ini` files, and infragistics controls...

Which of these, if it's even possible, will make it possible to create an installer that means the end user doesn't need to have the infragistics package etc installed? Are there any better alternatives?

Comment: If you are talking about NSIS - Visual & Installer extension that will not work in Express edition of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the Infragistics binaries then there is no way to run your project if the running machine has not the infragistics binaries available.
You need to distrubute them along with the required binaries for Crystal Report.

With Access the problem is different. If you use OleDb.Jet.4.0 (Access 2003 32 bit) then support is included directly in the framework. If you use ACE.12.0 then you need to install the required binaries from Microsoft (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255) and be sure to read [The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine while data export to MS ACCESS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17716207/the-microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine-w)

Comment: Hi Steve, thank you for the response. The client has Access, so this won't be a problem, but what do you mean by using the Infragistics and Crystal Reports binaries? How would I distribute them with the installer?

Comment: It means that you should look at the 'references' section of your project, take note of every assembly from Infragistics listed there and distribute the relative DLL along with your program. These DLLs could be found in the Infragistics installation folder or in the GAC of your PC. For the Crystal Report the problem is the same but I can't help you with that mammooth because I have ditched them long time ago. You should find some docs in their support that explains what DLL you should/can distribute

Comment: Thanks Steve, I'll give it a go