# Changed something in properties in C#, VB?

Tags: c#, vb.net, settings

I'm accidently changed something in properties(Visual studio 2012 c# Window form Application) and now when I am connecting to MS Access database an error is showing 
**`"Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 is not registered in your machine"`**

I created a new project tried to connect the same database, it is easily connected.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6649363/microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine)

Comment: This error happens when you set your CPU platforn to X64 or AnyCPU and you have installed the 32bit version of ACE.OLEDB (or viceversa)

Comment: it is not driver error I couldn't install anything

Comment: Checked .. no any issue

Comment: Please open the menu BUILD->Configuration Manager. What is the Active CPU platform?

Comment: You can find an explanation of the possible issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17716207/the-microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine-w/17716238#17716238