# "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0 provider is not registered on the local machine" but I have it installed already

Tags: asp.net, oledb, oledbconnection, oledbexception

I have the same problem as others but (in this case) I have already installed that component.

**UPDATE**:
I have Windows 10 x64, Office 2016 x64, MS Access Database Engine 2016 x64. Is a ASP.NET .NET Framework 4.5 target AnyCPU Visual Studio Solution (Web Site project).

The image is just for demonstrate that I have installed this OLEDB provider.

[image: Provider is registered!]

My code is:

```
"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR={1}'"
cmdExcel.Connection = connExcel
connExcel.Open()
```

The last line break and cause the Exception.

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17716207/the-microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine-w/17716238#17716238

Comment: x64, x64 ACE install

Comment: .Net is not SQL Code. You .Net code might be running a different bitness to your SQL Server (i.e. x86 instead of x64). Or your code might not even be running on the same SQL Server

Comment: The image is just to demonstrate that I have installed the provider that Visual Studio says I don't have.