# .NET Reading data from Excel 2007 file

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, excel

I'm creating a WinForm application that needs to get data from an excel spreadsheet.  Do I need to install Office 2007 on my DEV PC?  What about the PC that will run the WinForm application?  Also, can I use Office PIA without installing office on both my DEV and target PC?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

first step  implement method to get data from excel files

[These Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15793442/how-to-read-data-from-excel-file-using-c-sharp)

after  implement you dosent need to install excel if u need add dll  you most create embed resource your dll  with your  executable file

this answer help

[Code project Example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/528178/Load-DLL-From-Embedded-Resource)

Answer (score 0):

For development

1. [Configuring a Computer to Develop Office Solutions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398242.aspx)

[image]

And for end users:

1. [Office Solution Prerequisites for Deployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608617.aspx)
2. [How to: Install Prerequisites on End User Computers to Run Office Solutions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608608.aspx)

[image]