# Output is not in human readable format when writing content of an Excel sheet to console in C#

Tags: c#, excel, file

I'm trying to read an excel sheet and displaying contents to console. the code is here

```
  FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(@"E:\USERS\MyWorkbook.xlsx", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
  byte[] byteCode = new byte[fileStream.Length];
  fileStream.Read(byteCode, 0, (int)fileStream.Length);            
  foreach (var byteValue in byteCode)
  {
      Console.Write(Convert.ToChar(byteValue));
  }
  Console.ReadLine();
```

the output is

> PK♥♦¶ ♠   ! bî?h^☺  ?♦  ‼☻[Content_Types].xml ¢♦☻(  ☻
>
> ¬?ENA0►E÷HüCä-JÜ²5í?Ç↕*Q>AÄ?Æªc[?iiÿ??û►B¡§j7±↕IÜ{2ñIh²nm¶??Æ»R♀??EAU^←7/>ÅÇ
>   ì%¿↨↓?rZYï ¶←@1↓__?f? ?q·AR4DáAJ¬→h§▬>?a?UÇV◄ßÆ1♀ªZ"9EUAàNV_◄8EcO►aÑ‼Oji){^óa-I♦
>   ?"{Ü▬v^¥P!XS)bR1rú?K_s(,3O`▬_§ïßeÖ↔♦»ß1æ►@(?a?sí?►[í?☼öB·LA?F←I↔"fKlk↑--¿$♣?A
>   pN$å

What's wrong with it?

Comment: just follow this tutorial that will be help you https://bytescout.com/products/developer/spreadsheetsdk/read-write-excel.html

Comment: you read file as binary, you must use xcel object instead, there's plenty of exmaple.

Comment: the link above is a bad practice ( call GC and set obejct to null)

Comment: Because that's not the way to read a excel file pro-grammatically .. some good solution already given in your question already ..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the help of Oledb (Object Linking and Embedding Database). OLE DB is Microsoft's strategic low-level application program interface (API) for access to different data sources.

The objects in OLE DB consist mainly of a data source object, a session object, a command object, and a rowset object. An application using OLE DB would use this request sequence:

1. Initialize OLE.
2. Connect to a data source.
3. Issue a command.
4. Process the results.
5. Release the data source object and uninitialize OLE.

here is a link of previous stackoverflow answer how to use olddb to access data from excel.

[How to read data from excel file using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15793442/how-to-read-data-from-excel-file-using-c-sharp)

Here is Sample Code

```
string path = @"E:\USERS\MyWorkbook.xlsx";
//Create connection string to Excel work book
string excelConString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;Persist Security Info=False";

OleDbConnection excelCon = new OleDbConnection(excelConString);

excelCon.Open();

DataTable dtsheet = new DataTable();

dtsheet = excelCon.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, new object[] { null, null, null, "TABLE" });    

foreach (DataRow row in dtExcelSheet.Rows)
{ 
    Query = string.Format("Select * from [{0}]", row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString());
    //Create OleDbCommand to fetch data from Excel
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(Query, excelCon);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter(Query, excelCon);
    excelCon.Close();
    oda.Fill(ds);
    DataTable Exceldt = ds.Tables[0];

   foreach (DataRow dr in Exceldt.Rows)
   {
      //code to display
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide some demo code, showing how it's a solution to the question ..

Comment: @Moumit I have edited post with sample code. You can have a look.

Answer (score 4):

You should probably be looking into the office interop object model or using an oledb adapter.

Codeproject has some good resources on the object model here http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/696864/Working-with-Excel-using-Csharp

and there's a previous stackoverflow answer on how to use an oledb connection to query the data here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16051/6080982

Some sample code with office objects:

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

        Excel.Application app = new Excel.Application();
        Excel.Workbook wb = app.Workbooks.Open("path to a workbook");
        Excel.Worksheet sheet = (Excel.Worksheet)wb.Sheets[1];
        int lastrow = sheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count;
        int lastcol = sheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count;

        Excel.Range c1;
        Excel.Range c2;

        for (int i = 1; i <= lastrow; i++)
        {
            c1 = (Excel.Range)sheet.Cells[i, 1];
            c2 = (Excel.Range)sheet.Cells[i, lastcol];
            Excel.Range range = sheet.Range[c1, c2];

            foreach(Object o in (System.Array)range.Value)
            {
                if (o != null)
                {
                    Console.Write(o.ToString());
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: plus 1 and xlm read version https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc823095.aspx

Comment: Can you please provide some demo code, showing how it's a solution to the question

Answer (score 3):

Like others have mentioned, you should look into office interop object. Add the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` as reference into your project, you can usually find this dll at

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Visual Studio Tools for Office\PIA\Office15
```

Here's a code that might help you with what you want to do, I have added comments to help you understand each line better:

```
Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
//Points to the excel path
Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@"E:\USERS\MyWorkbook.xlsx");    
//Sheets[1] = First worksheet, modify this according to your need
Excel.Worksheet xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets[1];    
//UsedRange means the range of cells that has contents (are being used).
Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;

int rowCount = xlRange.Rows.Count;
int colCount = xlRange.Columns.Count;

for (int i = 1; i <= rowCount; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= colCount; j++)
        {
            var cellContent = xlWorksheet.Cells[i, j].Value;
            //To prevent exceptions due to null reference         
            if (cellContent != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(cellContent.ToString());
            }                  
        }
    }
```

First you use `.UsedRange` to figure out the maximum number of row and column that contains stuff. Then you simply do a nested loop and display the content in each cell using `Console.WriteLine` (Like what you intended).