# OleDbDataReader How to read number types?

Tags: c#, wpf, database, type-conversion, xls

Trying to read data from ***.XLS file**. I am able to read all the cell strings but **unable to read the numbers** in the cells. I have tried using .ToString() method with no success. Getting back a database **null**.

**Code:**

```
public xlsConverter(string excelFilePath, int numColumns)
        {
            string cnnStr = String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0}; Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=No;'", excelFilePath);
            string queryStr = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]";

            using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(cnnStr))
            {
                OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(queryStr, connection);
                connection.Open();
                OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    for(int i = 0; i <= numColumns; i++)
                    {
                        cleanedString.AppendFormat("{0}{1}", (reader[i].ToString()), "|");
                    }
                    cleanedString.AppendLine();
                }

                reader.Close();
            }
        }
```

> cleanedString.AppendFormat("Row[{0}], DataType[{1}], String[{2}],
>   Column[{3}] |-|", counter, (reader[i]).GetType(),
>   reader[i].ToString(), i);

**Produces:**

> Row[98], DataType[System.DBNull], String[], Column[4] |-|

**Column 4** contains mixed strings and numbers, eg: *1300, 2341, 5000, 4000 (DED), 1243*

Tried using “GetInt, GetValue, Parse, ‘casting’, ToString() etc”, but null is null! Anyone want to lead me in the right direction?

**Sample XLS file:**

https://github.com/abflett/adamflett_ca

https://github.com/abflett/adamflett_ca/blob/master/sample.xls

Comment: If you are certain it's a number, just cast to the type you wish. e.g. (int)reader[i];

Comment: Tried that one and even changed to: cleanedString.AppendFormat("Row[{0}], DataType[{1}], String[{2}], Column[{3}] |-|", counter, (reader[i]).GetType(), reader[i].ToString(), i); System.DBNull returned on cells that have a number data type. I think maybe I am loosing data with the command, query or connection string?

Comment: Can you give some sample data from the .xls file?

Comment: edited and provided sample.xls

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Took some digging but ended up being a simple fix.

The connection string was the issue.

```
string cnnStr = String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0}; Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1;ImportMixedTypes=Text;TypeGuessRows=0'", excelFilePath);
```

> ImportMixedTypes=Text;TypeGuessRows=0

^Was added!

Youtube video I found it at:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jhPp_Hz54BU

and already answerd here at stackoverflow:
[Help with a OleDB connection string for excel files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4551203/help-with-a-oledb-connection-string-for-excel-files)

Comment: For me `IMEX=1;ImportMixedTypes=Text;TypeGuessRows=0` was missing from my connection string. Thanks for posting.