# reading excel while the data is in table format

Tags: c#, excel

I have a Excel sheet, where the data is stored like a table structure as shown below. so there are multiple tables with different column names inside it. how to read the values of any specific row value. example how to read the value present against the Nominal voltage (which is 100v) either using epplus/OpenOffice xml
    Need help!

```
Operating range (table header)

Type of data    Unit    Value
Coolant volume  [l/min] Infineon AIIRF7669L2
Min voltage     [V]     0
Nominal voltage [V]     100 V
Voltage         [V]     60
Max voltage     [V]     75
Back EMF        [V/rpm] 340Aeff
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's possible to use something else you could use OleDB and use the Excel sheets like datatables in a database. 
But I'm sorry if you just can use epplus/OpenOffice.

But here you could read about OleDB and there is also an example.
[How to read data from excel file using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15793442/how-to-read-data-from-excel-file-using-c-sharp)