# Problem with checking differencies in two Excel using windows application form - c#

Tags: c#, excel, difference

I need to make a Windows application form to check differences in two Excel sheet (the two Excel sheet can have different number of rows and columns - the column name can be used  to know which column needs to be check to which column). I have to open 2 excel sheet, make the checking and generate a 3rd one to store the necessity information. I have a problem to open the two Excel sheet and get the data from them.

Could you help me?

Best regards,
Tom

Comment: Well if they're actual excel files (as opposed to CSV's or tab delimited files) then you'll want to use microsoft's COM interface for excel. Find out more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interop/how-to-access-office-onterop-objects

Also I think this question is more appropriate for: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Check one of the solutions here:
[How to read data from excel file using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15793442/how-to-read-data-from-excel-file-using-c-sharp)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.