# What's the fastest way to compare pairs of Excel programmatically?

Tags: c#, excel

For some form of Excel report regression, I need to programmatically compare pairs (new versus old) of Excel reports. These reports are relatively simple, no charts just numbers and just one sheet, but there is a large number of pairs (thousands).

I thought of using interop and opening each pairs for comparison cell by cell would be problematic and slow. Perhaps some way to hash the file, or convert to csvand compare as plain text would be better?

Comment: Navigating those files through OpenXml is a feasible option?

Comment: Comparing 10k rows with few columns will not take long in excel and you don’t need VBA to do so. You can open a 3rd sheet which in the same cell place you will enter a short if statement. And then just drag it left and down.

Comment: I'd look at using Linq-To-Excel - See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12996234/optimal-way-to-read-an-excel-file-xls-xlsx/12996544#12996544

Comment: @Balinti I'm trying to compare thousands of pairs of Excel, not thousands of cells. Of course I know how to do if statements :)