# How to get the series data from Excel

Tags: c#, excel

I have some following requirement. while import the excel(it consists chart) i need to get the chart series data from excel. how can i get? using c#

This is my excel file... i need to get the candle series data.. can you please help this

[image: This is my excel file]

Comment: What did you try? you have enough points to show you've been here long enough to know we dont just spew code..

Comment: i can't able to get the series data and didn't get any solution

Comment: don't forget he's also indian, he should be much better than us :D

Comment: why not @AkbarBasha we arent mind readers here, there are tons of examples of getting stuff out of excel.. so.. what have you done?

Answer (score -1):

If you could export the .csv from the xls you can:

```
        string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"yourFolder\yourCsv.csv");

        // Display the file contents by using a foreach loop.
        string[] arr;
        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
             //you get an array with each cell value
             arr=line.split(";")
             //do what you want with arr[1] which i suppose is the col you are interested to
        }
```

or if you want to use the .xls file format you could use [LinqToExcel](https://github.com/paulyoder/LinqToExcel)
as suggested here [Optimal way to Read an Excel file (.xls/.xlsx)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12996234/optimal-way-to-read-an-excel-file-xls-xlsx)