# Read xls files generically regardless of excel version

Tags: c#, excel

I was implementing a solution for importing `xls` files given by following [this posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15828/reading-excel-files-from-c-sharp) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12996234/optimal-way-to-read-an-excel-file-xls-xlsx). The following solution indeed works for sum excel files:

```
public XLSReader(string path, string worksheet = "Sheet1")
{
  Dictionary<string, string> props = new Dictionary<string, string>();
  props["Provider"] = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0";
  props["Data Source"] = path;
  props["Extended Properties"] = "Excel 12.0";

  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> prop in props)
  {
    sb.Append(prop.Key);
    sb.Append('=');
    sb.Append(prop.Value);
    sb.Append(';');
  }
  string properties = sb.ToString();

  using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(properties))
  {
    conn.Open();
    ds = new DataSet();

    //string columns = String.Join(",", columnNames.ToArray());
    using (OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(
      "SELECT *" + /*columns +*/ " FROM [" + worksheet + "$]", conn))
    {

      da.Fill(ds);
      dt = new DataTable[ds.Tables.Count];
      ds.Tables.CopyTo(dt, 0);
    }
    Console.WriteLine(ds.Tables.Count + " Tables");
  }
}
```

It is a class's constructor, and sum of the variables used here are defined on the class and only used here so sorry for any missing variable declarations.

The problem is, for some excel files it doesn't work (a link to such example is added at the end of the post), throwing me an 'External table is not in the expected format' eception. If I understand correctly, it depends on the excel's version and is influenced by the `props`'s string and properties given to the `OleDbConnetion`.

- Do I understand correctly or is there another problem in the code?
- How do I alter this to generically load any excel file?

[Link to example problematic xls file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/py88mwb9j211vwc/AA.xls?dl=0)

Comment: Can you post a sample Excel file that doesn't work?

Comment: @haindl Excel file posted.

Comment: It's a text file.

Comment: That's just a simple csv file. I would recommend to read csv's without the help of Excel.

Comment: And is there anyway to distinguished between the two Automatically assuming some of the files with `xls` ending are actually `csv`?

Comment: You can check the [signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures) at the beginning of the file. So you get the information if it is a .xls or a .xlsx and treat all other files as text.

Comment: for text files you can use different [connection string](https://www.connectionstrings.com/textfile/), but for .xls files with .xlsx extension you will have to rename the file to .xls