# C# NUnit 3 Data Driven from Excel

Tags: c#, excel, selenium, nunit, oledb

Hello I have the following file: testexcel.xlsx > sheet 1

[image]

I want to execute this test twice as there are 2 rows with data.

```
[Test]
[TestCaseSource("Data")]
public void Login(String username, String password)
{
    loginPageModel.DoLogin(username, password);
}
```

How can I convert that excel data into this kind of data as explained in [NUnit 3 official documentation](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/TestCaseSource-Attribute)?

```
static object[] Data = {
        new object[] {username, password}
    };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What i did is the following and it's working

I have the Test:

```
[Test TestCaseSource(typeof(ExcelDataParser),"BudgetData") Category("1")]
public void AchterBudget(string min, string max)
{
.....
}
```

The classe ExcelDataParser which reads the excel file by calling the method readExcelData() from the class ExcelReader

```
class ExcelDataParser
{
static string pth = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().CodeBase;
static string actualPath = pth.Substring(0, pth.LastIndexOf("bin"));
static string projectPath = new Uri(actualPath).LocalPath;
static string excelPath = projectPath + @"com.seloger.resources\excelData\";

public static IEnumerable<TestCaseData> BudgetData
{
  get
   {
      List<TestCaseData> testCaseDataList = new ExcelReader().ReadExcelData(excelPath + "AcheterBudgetData.xlsx");

if (testCaseDataList != null)
   foreach (TestCaseData testCaseData in testCaseDataList)
                                yield return testCaseData;
                    }
                }
    }
```

And this is the class ExcelReader which contains the method ReadExcelData that converts every row from the excel file to a TestCaseData:

```
class ExcelReader
    {
        public List<TestCaseData> ReadExcelData(string excelFile, string cmdText = "SELECT * FROM [Feuil1$]")
        {
            if (!File.Exists(excelFile))
                throw new Exception(string.Format("File name: {0}", excelFile), new FileNotFoundException());
            string connectionStr = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES\";", excelFile);
            var ret = new List<TestCaseData>();
            using (var connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionStr))
            {
                connection.Open();
                var command = new OleDbCommand(cmdText, connection);
                var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                if (reader == null)
                    throw new Exception(string.Format("No data return from file, file name:{0}", excelFile));
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    var row = new List<string>();
                    var feildCnt = reader.FieldCount;
                    for (var i = 0; i < feildCnt; i++)
                        row.Add(reader.GetValue(i).ToString());
                    ret.Add(new TestCaseData(row.ToArray()));
                }
            }
            return ret;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to read in the Excel file (see [Optimal way to Read an Excel file (.xls/.xlsx)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12996234/optimal-way-to-read-an-excel-file-xls-xlsx)) and then return the data from your `TestCaseSource`. I won't go into reading in the Excel file here because that is covered in the linked question and in many places on the web, but you just need to switch your `TestCaseSource` to a method and `yield return` or `Select` the results.

Don't forget that your `TestCaseSource` needs to be `public static` and it is better (but not required) to return `TestCaseData` instances.

Your code will look something like this.

```
public static IEnumerable Data()
{
    var rows = ReadExcel("testdata.xlsx");
    return rows.Select(row => new TestCaseData(row[0], row[1]));
}
```

Comment: thanks. But on the "return rows.select....." I´m facing the following error: "cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type". I have included "using System.Linq;" and "System.Data.Entity;" as read on other post... any clues?

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to separate the test data and code. Please take a look at [JsonSectionReader](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WonderTools.JsonSectionReader/).

This package provides the support for storing the test data in embedded json file, and it has excellent support of deserialization.