# save LINQ to XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I am trying to retrieve all values from excel sheet and storing in XML. How to store the variable value in .XML format?  Here is my code. I tried using writeXMl but its not in proper format. I want to save whatever is there in xlContent variable in .XML format.

```
var columnNames = new List<string>();
foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
{
    columnNames.Add(column.ColumnName);
}
var xlContent = new XElement("DocumentElement", from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
                        select new XElement("Assets", from columnName in columnNames
                        select new XElement(columnName.Replace(" ",""), row[columnName]))).ToString();


dt.WriteXml("C:\\Development\\MyAppln\\ExcelToXML\\Products.xml");
```

Comment: Try.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527790/how-can-i-write-to-an-excel-spreadsheet-using-linq

Comment: @ Jidheesh Rajan the link not answer to my question

Answer (score 0):

Use the [XElement.Save()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360171.aspx) method:

```
xlContent.Save("C:\\Development\\MyAppln\\ExcelToXML\\Products.xml");
```

Declaring xlContent as `var` and then having a `ToString()` in the end makes `xlContent` a `string`. If you remove the `ToString()`, the xlContent will properly be declared as `XElement`, and you will be able to get a `Save()` method.

The xml declaration is automatically added when `Save()` is called. For further reference check: [XElement.Save Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360171.aspx)

Now if you do not want the default declaration, you may add your `XElement` into an `XDocument` and then define the attributes of the declaration:

```
    XDocument xDoc = new XDocument
        (
            new XDeclaration("1.0","Windows-1252","yes"),
            xlContent
        );
    xDoc.Save("C:\\Development\\MyAppln\\ExcelToXML\\Products.xml");
```

Comment: there is not any xlContent.save method available. its a var.

Comment: Even if it is a Var, since you are declaring it as an XElement, it will be an XElement and have all its properties and methods.

Comment: but there is not xlContent.Save(); any other way to do this?

Comment: It is because you have a `ToString()` in the end. Remove that and try again.

Comment: @ jyparask : Thx. problem is solved. now i want to explicitly declared first line of XML as <?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>

Comment: I think it is automaticaly added when Save. Check your file.

Comment: @ jyparask No am getting as <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> i dont want encoding instead i want to use <?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>

Comment: Please see my update on wrapping xlContent in an XDocument. It is the code i have on the bottom. The arguments of XDeclaration are in order `version`, `encoding`,`standalone`. Put there whatever you want.